# How can I exec either a shell script or an executable?

Tags: c, exec

This is a school project I'm working on.

I'm writing a web server. If the requested resource has the extension 'cgi', I need to fork and exec the program. If the cgi is a compiled executable, this works:

```
execl(path, (char*) 0);
```

But if the cgi program is a script that needs to be interpreted, I need to do something like this:

```
execl("/bin/sh", path, path, (char*) 0);
```

How can I write my code so it will handle either scenario? How does my shell do this? Should I use the `file` program to determine if it's an executable or text, and if it's text, then assume it needs to be interpreted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need to invoke `"/bin/sh"` explicitly if it's a script?

As long as the script has execute permission and the proper [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top, you should be able to execute it just as if it were an executable.

Comment: @TrevorDixon: What happens when you execute the script from your shell prompt? And what does the first line of the script look like?

Comment: Darnit, you're right. I had a typo! My test script was missing the "bang" part of the shebang. I feel embarrassed. Thank you!

Comment: @TrevorDixon: Actually, I'm surprised it didn't work without the `!`. A script with execute permissions starting with `#` is normally executed by `/bin/sh`. It might depend on your OS, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the shell to run a command for you using the `-c` option.

If the command is a shell built-in, or a shell script, the shell will run it; if it is an external command, the shell will exec the binary.

Try this and see if it works for you:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", path, (char*) 0);
```

EDIT: corrected the above call.  This should work now; I tested with

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "set", NULL);
```

and my test program echoed the default shell variables.  Then I tested with

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/clear", NULL);
```

and my test program cleared the screen of the terminal emulator.

NOTE: the good thing about this answer is that it will run anything you can run from the shell.  So, it will run built-in shell commands, and it will run shell scripts that don't have a proper `#!/path/to/interpreter` first line.  If all the shell scripts you will ever want to run have the proper `#!` first line, you don't need this.  This offers a slightly more robust solution at the cost of exec-ing a shell that might not be needed.

Comment: Error: "cannot execute binary file"

Comment: That wont work. Remember that the first argument (i.e. `argv[0]`) to any program is the actual program name...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to calling `execl()`.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the file has exec permission, if not warn your user.
You can use the lstat function of the GlibC to perform that.
Then use execve from the GlibC feeding it with path and the arguments list (You can also get the env var from the main, I recommend you to give the environment to your programs instead of giving (char *)0 which is a NULL pointer)